# Why do they sing Nirvana in Pan?

Tags: soundtrack, pan

In the recent adaption of Peter Pan, [*Pan*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3332064/), the workers and captain sing *Smells Like Teen Spirit* by Nirvana together.

Why did they choose this specific song to sing together?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From *[The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2015/10/19/pan-film-joe-wright_n_8330856.html)* who interviewed Joe Wright, the director:

> One of the most memorable scenes in 'Pan', Joe Wright’s lavish Peter
>   Pan prequel is when young Londoner Peter is first transported to
>   Neverland, and encounters Blackbeard, an out-of-control Hugh Jackman,
>   tyrannising thousands of pirates to mine for fairy dust. All this is
>   accompanied by the anthemic chants of Nirvana’s ‘Smells Like Teen
>   Spirit’, and it’s a moment that wasn’t even in the script.
>
> “The script didn’t have anything like that,” remembers Joe now. “He
>   was just supposed to walk on and make a speech.
>
> “But during rehearsals, we had a ridiculous pirate boot camp for a
>   week, so Hugh could get to know the other pirates. ***We were playing
>   music, one day that song came on, everyone started singing, pogoing,
>   and here we are...*** it was one of those films, where we were liberated to
>   come up with the craziest, silliest ideas and make them real.”

Comment: So in other words "no reason whatsoever" :)